# Microsoft Teams App added or removed from personal scope events missing

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams

I try to write an app for Microsoft Teams which does include a Bot.

The bot should write a welcome message as soon as the app is installed by the user in his personal scope. Additionally I want to be informed when the user uninstalled an app.

There are events when a new user is added/removed to a team (onTeamsMemberAdded/onTeamsMemberRemoved) in which the bot is installed, but is there also something for the personal scope?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`onTeamsMemberAdded` should deal with personal scope as well, and it will enable you to send a welcome message. However, there is unfortunately no way to get notified when your bot is removed. `onTeamsMemberRemoved` only applies when your bot is part of a group chat, or channel, and only tells if other *users* have been removed. This is a missing feature in Teams right now.